# Biblatex: Where to put external abstract files?

Tags: biblatex, external-files

In §3.11.8 ("External Abstracts and Annotations") of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf), it says that it is possible to put abstracts in external `.tex` files rather than storing them in the `.bib` file directly.

To do this, it says you must name the `.tex` file `bibabstract-citekey.tex`, where "`citekey`" is the citekey for the associated entry in the `.bib` file.

The documentation does not say anything about where these external abstract files should be stored. I assumed it would be possible to keep them in a local `texmf` tree, but that seems to not be the case.

I've only been able to get the abstract to print when the `bibabstract-citekey.tex` is in the same folder as the main `.tex` file.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the intended behavior?

Here's a three-part MWE:

### `main.tex`

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=reading, % a style that prints abstracts
    loadfiles=true % must be set to true for external abstract files
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-example.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{chomsky2013}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### `biblatex-example.bib`

```
@Article{chomsky2013,
  author                      = {Chomsky, Noam},
  doi                         = {10.1016/j.lingua.2012.12.003},
  langid                      = {american},
  pages                       = {33--49},
  title                       = {Problems of Projection},
  issn                        = {0024-3841},
  journaltitle                = {Lingua},
  date                        = {2013-06},
  editor                      = {Rizzi, Luigi},
  issuetitle                  = {Syntax and Cognition},
  issuesubtitle               = {Core Ideas and Results in Syntax},
  number                      = {1},
  volume                      = {130}
}
```

### `bibabstract-chomsky2013.tex`

```
With the crystallization of the ``generative enterprise'' half a century ago, two concepts became salient: the initial state and final states of the language faculty, respectively, UG (the genetic component) and I-languages. Since then inquiry has gained far greater scope and depth. It has also led to sharpening of fundamental principles of language. At first, descriptive adequacy appeared to require rich and complex assumptions about UG. A primary goal has always been to overcome this deficiency. Core properties of concern have included compositionality, order, projection (labeling), and displacement. Early work assigned the first three to phrase structure rules and the last to the transformational component. Simplification of computational procedures suggests that compositionality and displacement (along with the ``copy theory'') fall together while order may be a reflex of sensorimotor externalization, conclusions that have far-reaching consequences. As for labeling, minimal computation restricts options to the few that have considerable empirical support.
\endinput
```

I'm only able to get the abstract to print when `bibabstract-chomsky2013.tex` is saved in the same directory as `main.tex`. It does not print when `bibastract-chomsky2013.tex` is saved in a local `texmf` tree (in my case, `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/`).

Comment: So I figured out the answer about halfway through writing this question: it seems `biblatex` will find the external file so long as it is somewhere below `<texmf>/tex`. Presumably, the best practice would be to create a dedicated folder such as `<texmf>/tex/latex/biblatex/abstracts/`. I'll wait to answer my own question in case anyone else has a better suggestion. I figured the question is still worth asking, since this isn't mentioned in the documentation (might be worth updating the documentation).

Comment: Just for clarity: have you changed your `TEXMFHOME`? I would've thought you'd have something like `~/Library/texmf/{bibtex,tex,doc,...}` as the "texmf home".

Comment: @jon No, that's what I have as TEXMFHOME. You can put `biblatex-example.bib` and `bibabstract-chomsky2013.bib` inside `<texmf>/bibtex/bib/` and it will print everything but the abstract. It seems that external abstract files must go somewhere below `<texmf>/tex/`. It'd be nice if this were documented, since the intuitive place to put the external files (at least in my mind) doesn't work. `:p`

Comment: Intuition is a tricky thing.  These are `.tex` files and so need to be within the `tex` hierarchy not the `bibtex` hierarchy, even though they are associated with bib files... :)

Comment: @AlanMunn Indeed ... `:)` Alright, well, I guess I'll go ahead and answer this. @anyone: feel free to comment on or edit my answer if you think there's a better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are `.tex` files, `biblatex` will find the external abstract file so long as it is somewhere in `<texmf>/tex/` (**not** `<texmf>/bibtex/`). Moreover, since these files are meant for use by `biblatex`, it would presumably make the most sense to put them in `<texmf>/tex/latex/biblatex/`.

And, for the sake of organization, you might as well create a dedicated folder for all external abstracts, such as `<texmf>/tex/latex/biblatex/abstracts/`.

So, if you put `bibabstract-chomsky2013.tex` inside `<texmf>/tex/latex/biblatex/abstracts/`, then `biblatex` will find and print the abstract correctly.

---

<sup>`<texmf>` is shorthand for a local `texmf` tree. How you set this up depends on your TeX distribution (TeX Live/MacTeX or MiKTeX). If you do not know how to set up a local `texmf` tree but would like to set one up, see [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/32888)</sup>